# How can I add an extra operator overload for a class outside of it's original header?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I am using DirectXMath.h where all multiplications and operations are done with XMVECTOR(a SIMD wrapper) and for storage is used XMFLOAT3 which contains 3 floats.However in this specific piece of code I really need to add a *** operator** for XMFLOAT3(for both XMFLOAT3*XMFLOAT3 and XMFLOAT3*float).Can I do that?Or must I tamper with the DirectXMath headers in the SDK?

Comment: You **can** do that, but you should wonder why they didn't make it already...

Comment: I think they want to encourage people to use XMVECTOR more,they even added a * operator to XMVECTOR even tho there's alredy XMVectorMultiply xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go right ahead, just define `operator*`:

```
XMFLOAT3 operator*(XMFLOAT3 l, XMFLOAT3 r) {
    XMVECTOR lvec(XMLoadFloat3(&l));
    XMVECTOR rvec(XMLoadFloat3(&r));
    //Perform operations
}

XMFLOAT3 operator*(XMFLOAT3 l, float r) {
    XMVECTOR lvec(XMLoadFloat3(&l));
    //Perform operations
}

XMFLOAT3 operator*(float l, XMFLOAT3 r) {
    XMVECTOR rvec(XMLoadFloat3(&r));
    //Perform operations
}
```

Comment: i see,the problem is,I made 2 overloads(one for XMFLOAT3*XMFLOAT3 and another for XMFLOAT3*float,but in the second definition,it hightlights my operator and gives an error:   XMFLOAT3 operator*(real scalar);  <<operator requires parameter with class or enum type

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you **could** define your overload, but only as a free function, not as a member function.

So you could do something like this (assuming this is the overload you're interested in):

```
XMFLOAT3 operator*(XMFLOAT3 a, XMFLOAT3 b) {
    // whatever
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course, in C++ you can provide an operator overload as a free function, like this:

```
XMFLOAT3 operator*(XMFLOAT3 left, XMFLOAT3 right)
{
    ...
}
```

if this will be employed in performance-sensitive code, check if pass-by-value vs pass-by-const reference makes any difference in emitted code/performance.

Answer (score 3):

```
XMFLOAT3 operator*(const XMFLOAT3& a, const XMFLOAT3& b){
    XMFLOAT3 ans; 
    ...
    return ans;
}
```

Mind you that this returns a copy of the answer and does not modify any of the 2 operands. This is true to the semantics of the `*` operator.